# Transpose data in text file

Tags: perl, awk

I have a text file in the format below:

```
Name: John
Age: 25
Location: CA

Name: Mac
Age: 24
Location: CA

Name: Patrick
Age: 25
Location: CA

Name: Christian
Age: 25
Location: CA
```

I looking for help to transpose the data using either Perl or awk.

```
Name    Age Location
John    25  CA
Mac 24  CA
Patrick 25  CA
Christian   25  CA
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking for this?

```
kent$  awk -F'\n|: ' -v RS="" 'NR==1{print $1,$3,$5}{print $2,$4,$6}' file 
Name Age Location
John 25 CA
Mac 24 CA
Patrick 25 CA
Christian 25 CA
```

if you want to let output look prettier, pipe the output to `|column -t` (values don't contain spaces)  or use `printf` in awk.

```
kent$  awk -F'\n|: ' -v RS="" 'NR==1{print $1,$3,$5}{print $2,$4,$6}' f|column -t
Name       Age  Location
John       25   CA
Mac        24   CA
Patrick    25   CA
Christian  25   CA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -00 -nE 'say join"\t", /^(\w+)/mg if $. ==1;say join"\t", /(\w+)$/mg' file
```

output

```
Name    Age     Location
John    25      CA
Mac     24      CA
Patrick 25      CA
Christian       25      CA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Name","Age","Location"} {print $2,$4,$6}' RS= file
Name Age Location
John 25 CA
Mac 24 CA
Patrick 25 CA
Christian 25 CA
```